# Manage multiple recipients with one transaction id

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am building an e-commerce website where I need to charge the buyer for a purchase e.g. buyer purchased an item in 20$, then 18$ will be transferred to seller account and 2$ will be transferred to application owner as fee. I need to do this transfer in a single transaction.

1. I can do it using adaptive payments with multiple recipients but when redirect buyer to Paypal for payment then page shows invoice with payment distribution (between owner and seller) which I don't want to show. I attached screenshot for the same as well. So, I dropped this option.

[image: split payment screenshot]

2. Another option is I can collect full payment e.g. 20$ to owner's account when buyer transfers payment and then transfer seller's share in another transaction. But in this case I need to manage two different transaction IDs which will be hard to manage in case of a refund.

How can I distribute payment between multiple recipients in a single transaction without letting buyer know about it (case 1), and how can I manage a refund (case 2)?

Comment: Sincerely, if recording and refunding two separate transactions as two separate transactions is “hard to manage”, perhaps you shouldn't be working on code that handles payments? Accounting requires records of everything, and a great deal of nuance and detail is involved. That's the nature of the beast.

Comment: @coreyward yes do agree but how you can manage a parent(merchant) account and child(seller) account along with transferred amount in a single transaction and it will ease you while refunding as only merchant should have the permission to refund. Stripe do the same.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not how it works behind the scenes. The interface should be simple, but the implementation is not.

Comment: I'm asuming you are using Parallel Payment in Adaptive. But have you try using Chained Payment? Buyer could only see single receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement with *PayPal adaptive chained payment*.

Adaptive Chained payments enable a sender(buyer) to send a single payment to a primary receiver(You). The primary receiver keeps part of the payment and send remaining money secondary receivers. In this process, the sender(buyer) sees only primary receiver(you) not secondary receivers.

Please check below link for more info about PayPal adaptive chained payment:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicChainedPayment-curl-etc/